# Impact of WHERE clause on performance

Tags: sql

I am no SQL expert and I am trying to optimize a query I'm making. Assume the following situation: I want to extract all the unpaid bills for a list of clientID. My current query looks a bit like this:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID, BILL_ID, BILL_PAID  
FROM T_BILLS 
WHERE CLIENT_ID IN [LIST OF IDs] 
  AND BILL_PAID = 'No'
```

My first thinking was that the second where condition (BILL_PAID = 'No') is reducing the number of rows returned thus making the query faster. My company server has a time limit for running SQL Queries. Right now I'm busting it. I know I could slice my LIST OF IDs into smaller lists but before doing so I was wondering if eliminating the second where clause could help. The logic being I would get more data but that might require less computing. The extra data could easily be filtered out later with excel.

Comment: I am assuming you are indexing on client_id and bills_paid?

Comment: If there are no indexes on T_BILLS for client id and bill paid that would make a huge difference. Such a simple where clause shouldn't be creating this much performance hit. How many rows are there in T_BILLS? 
select count(*) from t_bills

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments if you don't have indexes on `CLIENT_ID` and `BILL_PAID` then add them. Also consider change `BILL_PAID` type from string to int or tiny int (model enum or boolean type if applicable) to bust the index on that column even more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot make any changes to the database itself. I assume that there are indexes on all relevant columns tough. The example I gave in the question is for demonstration only, the real database is much more complex. My question is more theoretical… The second where clause being optional for me I am wondering if it would be faster to omit it and just getting more data.